# Navigation toggle does not function correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code where this silver block on click should toggle the navigation bar. It does trigger once and does not for the second try to toggle the navigation bar back. I am assuming this code has some minor bug and I could not find what.

Here is the code.

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var navStatus = true;
  if (navStatus == true) {
    document.getElementById("closenav").style.left = "-300px";
    navStatus = false;
  } else if (navStatus == false) {
    document.getElementById("closenav").style.left = "0px";
    navStatus = true;
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #272727;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

nav div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav id="closenav">
  <div onclick="toggleNav()"> </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: plus 1 for good example and clear question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define you variable `var navStatus = true` outside the `toggleNav()` function otherwise your variable `navStatus` value will be always `true` on every click as it is stated at the first line of your function...Also just use `else` instead of `else if`

```js
var navStatus = true;
function toggleNav() {
  if (navStatus == true) {
    document.getElementById("closenav").style.left = "-300px";
    navStatus = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("closenav").style.left = "0px";
    navStatus = true;
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #272727;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

nav div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav id="closenav">
  <div onclick="toggleNav()"> </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same w/o the extra explanation so I guess your's better